# Interfacing DS18B20 sensor to Raspberry pi in long distance

Tags: ds18b20

I have a Raspberry Pi connected with two `ds18b20` temperature sensors. `-sensor1` is fixed on the outside of my garage (distance 20m from raspberry Pi) `-sensor2` is just connected in a breadboard near the Raspberry Pi. Everything is working well.

I decided to add `-sensor3`, located outside and 20m from the Raspberry Pi.

Now when I type: `cd /sys/bus/w1/devices`

If get this: `c0-40a000061005 c2-246056869800 c2-247056869000 d0-008000001000 w1_bus_master1`

Instead of: `28-..... 28-..... 28-.....`

Each sensor ref should be start with `28-.....`

What is happening with my sensors? If unplugged the `sensor1`, then everything is well. If I unplug `sensor3` and let only `sensor1` and `sensor2` everything is well.

What modification do we have to do when sensor are located far from the Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 1):

There is a good tutorial called "Guidelines for Reliable Long Line 1-Wire Networks" that you can Google.  It recommends using CAT5 Ethernet cable for your connections.  You can find info on driving circuits for the 1-Wire bus by Googling "Choosing the Right 1-Wire Master for Embedded Applications".

Your setup should be able work, given that it does not appear to go beyond the limits described in the first document.